# I need to extract value from JSON response only if the key "has_products" = true . Is it possible to extract in Jmeter?

Tags: jmeter

My Json Response is as below:

```
{  
   "id":2,
   "parent_id":1,
   "has_products":false,
   "has_categories":true,
   "image":"",
   "image_thumbs":[  ],
   "name":"Default Category",
   "categories":[  
      {  
         "id":3,
         "parent_id":2,
         "has_products":false,
         "has_categories":true,
         "image":"https:\/\/storage.googleapis.com\/gcs-rezolve-commerce-engine-dev-media\/1%2F26%2Fcategory%2Fimages_7_.jpg?GoogleAccessId=rcedev@ferrous-layout-183111.iam.gserviceaccount.com&Expires=1515750870&Signature=BUVCdagE09Do%2B%2B6S9FXzmGUCJQP4QYHvoOuKOuLUQz9pJGwtwtkVF6h%2BuTzo5Jdqv%2F%2B4ACIw8WCWoT%2B8KQgNDpXA%2FCY2dkCDsfxb1VRXS0ff5dp4%2F2cq3WjE%2B8biudDXvhQvSWYx%2FyS%2FAYKkK%2FIXRqQ%2FlimDIYUR%2BRgdH6aEze4FNW5vCtGAHK%2BlscQ9GSFeG%2BN6KxMwFbjNpNNZT8KZ%2BLpdKbiHca%2Fk86TeYkmnvICdHpnaDqQJHGbofH%2BFPcbOWnjVCn9uD4gJQnfS4Y7a4OWdhG1q60Kr6KNpKmSOhOcD1P1NHFTn8SYI6GemGJPUXZ8Y3A40etORw1yfJC4M4Q%3D%3D",
         "image_thumbs":[  

         ],
         "name":"Home Decors",
         "categories":null
      },
      {  
         "id":4,
         "parent_id":2,
         "has_products":false,
         "has_categories":true,
         "image":"https:\/\/storage.googleapis.com\/gcs-rezolve-commerce-engine-dev-media\/1%2F26%2Fcategory%2F332034-jewelry.png?GoogleAccessId=rcedev@ferrous-layout-183111.iam.gserviceaccount.com&Expires=1515750870&Signature=OxdyQ6mYX5Shoz4pBf40MZr9I9PFdYUqD3Rihbn8EOpbj%2FekHSFiWGdUYZ1HeZmpB9mZ49qhKh3b0E25H%2FRPVvzv6MURzYOg4EfRa66KrjFAQVP5WbgC5dVzpKc2Nh8FWn4%2FgA70gQ1mE3Uh1KF62Tw2aFvlbughPM5ijC2j35xHTAYcnNhr2Pcx4%2B9%2BWVHecXCdvw%2Fy3CMrgmZGZFSfALNBsiSM8IKKtRXwqHqVRg9CwutbaVL5zDd0GbTdBhwZLlJxqAx9Z1RE4l78Rv3bA2BeLhk5OqX2ajU5YYEQC69tTm0Mq9jzNF7%2F9zhtwCsqDfiygmdMKs9D7vDqD0xD%2Fg%3D%3D",
         "image_thumbs":[  
            "https:\/\/storage.googleapis.com\/gcs-rezolve-commerce-engine-dev-media\/1%2F26%2Fcategory%2F332034-jewelry_thumb_400x376.png?GoogleAccessId=rcedev@ferrous-layout-183111.iam.gserviceaccount.com&Expires=1515750870&Signature=bOX4Z8EZwHb80ZNWtJ%2BrTq5hkUMNkTMGrtjk%2BvEyJ9H0XSDUMsmZVgMjgZVprgc23oLBR2SCDGvLNJKkCij2GIX1X9HT7QCFt4uLgvFy%2FmATHDcI9AOL55P8ypv7GJHBeUU7jdJKl5o641Uvf2s22yTCZpJenIiJCzJyxGAN%2BRV%2FwyD0OXkcTYjgwpJ5zi6SK%2BOYY5EGfTqFQBEbuG9WUAvNgeY3fCFgWoRgrp2XuxM5meXlcT7WA%2FZzt6wougjimBQsdF03s04Kq3cR6jsiL6aZFjhQacToBtkLFF7xY30dQr%2FO0D3tgs57QJXdD45QPBX4dAhgV2fSo%2BDK4D1kwQ%3D%3D"
         ],
         "name":"jewelry",
         "categories":null
      },
      {  
         "id":10,
         "parent_id":2,
         "has_products":true,
         "has_categories":false,
         "image":"",
         "image_thumbs":[  

         ],
         "name":"Ring Collection",
         "categories":null
      }
   ]
}
```

Can any one help me on this ?

Comment: what is the value that you want to extract?

Comment: Yes i need to extract id only

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming that the value you want to extract is the **id**, then add a [JSON Extractor](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#JSON_Extractor) with the below configurations:

- **Variable names :** the name of the variable which will hold the value.
- **JSON Path expressions :** `$.categories[?(@.has_products == true)].id`
- **Match Numbers :** `1` // use `-1` if you want to extract all id values which pass the condition.
- **Default values :** NOT_FOUND

Reference:

- [advanced-usage-json-path-extractor-jmeter](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/advanced-usage-json-path-extractor-jmeter) but use Core JMeter JSON Extractor instead of the plugin mentioned in blog